# Formatting a Time value on Ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, time, formatting, ionic3, hour

I need to find the way to format a time, I tried with angular pipe, but this works with date type values.

I need to be able to remove the seconds to values of the hours shown, example:

1:45:00 change to 1:45 pm or 1:45 p.m. M.

Comment: Is "1:45:00" a instance of Date or just a string ?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your date is a instance of [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) you can use the built in [angular date pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe) with the predefined format `shortTime` or a custom format:

```
<p> {{date | date:'shortTime'}} </p>

<p> {{date | date:'hh:mm'}} </p>
```

`shortTime` is equivalent to `'h:mm a'` and will produce results like 9:03 AM.

The custom format `'hh:mm'` will produce results like 09:03.

---

If your date is just a string you could use the built in [slice pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/SlicePipe) to remove the parts you want to get rid of:

```
<p> {{"1:45:00" | slice:0:4}} </p>
```

Which will output 1:45.

Also see this [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-gdrg6h?embed=1&file=pages/home/home.html) for the different options.

Anyway I'd reccomend using real Date objects or [Moment.js objects](https://momentjs.com/) over bare strings, it makes things a lot easier, especially once you start comparing dates or calculating with dates.

Comment: The first line reads "I need to find the way to format a time, I tried with angular pipe, but this works with date type values."

Comment: The question is not too informative on what type of data is used, so I tried to cover different possibilites... For the case that the date is only a string, I recommend using the slice pipe.

Answer (score 2):

Use Moment.js .here you can convert to any time format

1 - Install via NPM:

```
npm install moment -S
```

2 - Import in your Typescript file:

```
import moment from 'moment';
```

3 - Use in your Typescript file:

```
let dateString = "22-04-2017"; //whatever date string u have
let dateObject = moment(dateString, "DD-MM-YYYY").toDate();
```

Comment: momentJS is a awesome  to calculate date difference. even it can  add/minus days/hours/weeks and converting between string, moment and date object.

Answer (score 0):

If this is format is always the case you can manipulate the string with JavaScript/TypeScript.

```
  myTime = '1:45:00'

  showTime() {
    var result = 
    this.myTime.substring(
      0, (this.myTime.length - 3) )+ ' pm';
    console.log(result);
  }
```

If you have more complicated cases You could use a library like Momentjs.
https://momentjs.com/

This is where you can find what you need in the docs.
https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/

Answer (score 0):

```
you can use a custom pipe 

transform(timeString: string) {
    let time = timeString.slice(0, 5);
    let current_hour = timeString.slice(0, 2);
    if (parseInt(current_hour) > 12) {
      time = time + " PM";
    } else {
      time = time + " AM";
    }
    return time;
  }
```